# Apple Photos: cannot open library

Tags: photos, monterey

Not infrequently, I'll launch Photos and see the message "Cannot Open Library."

This is pretty scary, but every time, if I open the Photos Library using "Show Package Contents", I'll find a Photos.sqlite.lock file in the /database folder inside. If I delete this file, Photos will launch normally with the Photos Library.

Anyone else? Any idea why this is happening? This happened in Big Sur, and now it's happening in Monterey.

Comment: An internet search for "repair photos library" led me to this solution https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204967

Comment: Is another program or process that uses the Photos library running when this happens? (Can check in Activity Monitor). Closing it should unlock the Photos database. Also, is your Photos library stored locally on your Mac or on shared network drive or external drive?